# Custom sorting and calling for columns in R

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe, paste

Got 100 columns with currency data not sorted in a specific order. However, there is one column of spot rates and one for forward rates for each currency. They can all be identified by their name which are in the format USDXXX (XXX=ticker for currency, e.g. GBP,EUR) and XXX1F.

Example:

```
> set.seed(123)
> DF1=data.frame(matrix(rnorm(60),10,6))
> names(DF1)=c("USDEUR","USDGBP","USDZAR","EUR1F","ZAR1F","GBP1F")
> DF1
        USDEUR     USDGBP     USDZAR       EUR1F       ZAR1F       GBP1F
1  -0.56047565  1.2240818 -1.0678237  0.42646422 -0.69470698  0.25331851
2  -0.23017749  0.3598138 -0.2179749 -0.29507148 -0.20791728 -0.02854676
3   1.55870831  0.4007715 -1.0260044  0.89512566 -1.26539635 -0.04287046
4   0.07050839  0.1106827 -0.7288912  0.87813349  2.16895597  1.36860228
5   0.12928774 -0.5558411 -0.6250393  0.82158108  1.20796200 -0.22577099
6   1.71506499  1.7869131 -1.6866933  0.68864025 -1.12310858  1.51647060
7   0.46091621  0.4978505  0.8377870  0.55391765 -0.40288484 -1.54875280
8  -1.26506123 -1.9666172  0.1533731 -0.06191171 -0.46665535  0.58461375
9  -0.68685285  0.7013559 -1.1381369 -0.30596266  0.77996512  0.12385424
10 -0.44566197 -0.4727914  1.2538149 -0.38047100 -0.08336907  0.21594157
```

I was trying to call the DF1 columns with `paste`, but quickly figured out that didn't work. For instance

```
> paste("USD",ticker[[1]][1],"_Last",sep="")
```

returns

```
[1] "USDEUR"
```

but

```
DF1$paste("USD",ticker[[1]][1],sep="")
```

does not return anything, unlike

```
DF1$USDEUR
```

I'm interested in how to access the columns by using some non-generic command with the tickernames in the list. I've tried putting it into a function but can't get it to work there either. The reason why I want to do this is to find the returns between the pairs of the spots and the forwards.

Comment: Instead of `DF1$paste("USD",ticker[[1]][1],sep="")`  try `DF1[,paste("USD",ticker[[1]][1],sep="")]`

Comment: Yeah that should work much better... Thanks :D